# Can't access my server when connected to company's VPN

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, networking, vpn, ufw

So I hosted a website on a server inside the company network. I could access it through the company's VPN and also without VPN (from within the company). I installed Nginx (and ufw) and after a few minutes i couldn't access my server through the VPN.

I have uninstalled Nginx, disabled ufw, but still it doesn't work. I can ssh to it from within the company, but not when I am connected to the VPN.

I tried:
`ssh -v 192.168.1.241`

It gives the following output:

```
OpenSSH_9.4p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.241 [192.168.1.241] port 22.
```

I then tried:
`nc -vz 192.168.1.241 22`

But it also times out.

The strange thing is that
`nc -vz 192.168.1.241 80` responds with `success`. But I can't really visit the website.

Comment: Contact your company network administrator.

Comment: @AlexD I did, he doesn't understand it either. I just think he has some pre defined templates for spinning up virtual machines and doesn't know a lot about how the networking works.

Comment: If this device is not owned by you, contact the Responsible Person. Mostly verify which ips will be used, as you hide the entire Network configuration. There might be using the same network which might collide.